# How do I exclude modules from metro bundler?

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

I have a dependency in my React Native project that dynamically requires `react-native-fs`. The depdency expects me to install and configure it on my own. I don't need the function that calls this require. I'd like to not have to install and configure `react-native-fs`, since I don't need the function that uses it.

When I try to run my app, I get an error saying that the module could not be resolved.

In metro.config.js, I found an option `resolver.blockList`, but I can't seem to figure out a way to make it ignore `react-native-fs`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about it incorrectly. Metro bundler isn't looking for *modules* to be blacklisted, it's looking for *files*. By blacklisting the file containing the function doing the dynamic require, I was able to stop the dynamic import from ever happening.